# keep only the first blob in the binary Image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I applied a threshold to a grayscale image and I got a binary Image with white regions, `BW`. I want to know how I can label the binary image, `BW`, and keep  only the first blob as a mask.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html):

```
>> l = bwlabel( BW ); %// for BW your binary image
>> first = l == 1; %// select the first blob
>> figure; imagesc( first ); axis image; %// show it
```